# вместо папки получаю полный путь к ней (c#)

Tags: c#

есть вот такой код:

```
foreach (string dI in Directory.GetDirectories(argument))
{
    string dirs += dI + "^";
}
```

проблема в том что к примеру вместо папки `Public` я получаю `C:\Users\Public`
так же я пробовал

```
string dirs = string.Join("^", Directory.GetDirectory(@"C:\").Select(path => Path.GetDirectoryName(path)));
```

но он не работает

Comment: может решается проще, но первое что пришло в голову - делать сплит строки по слешу и брать последний элемент массива, что-то типо `var x = path.Split("\"); var y = x[x.Count()-1]`

Comment: я думал об этом, но мне кажеться это слишком костыльно

Comment: вроде это то, что тебе надо - https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread434271.html

Comment: Path.GetDirectoryName( dI ) не оно? Ещё [вопрос на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/getting-the-folder-name-from-a-full-filename-path).

Comment: нет, оно работает не так как мне нужно, и я его использовал в 2 примере

Comment: @Pekor нет, там нет нужного мне ответа

Comment: Ну как нет?! А [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32650679/3129992)?!

Comment: он из директории берет пред последнюю папку, а мне нужна последняя, + это костыль своего рода

Comment: Из Вашего вопроса, в принципе, мало понятно какие задачи Вы преследуете.  Если не последнюю директорию, то какую Вам необходимо получить?! Вы же сами писали, что из `C:\Users\Public` Вам нужно получить `Public`?! Что и когда Вы находите и какие рамки по производительности? У Вас уже были проблемы с производительностью? Опишите полность Вашу задачу, дополните вопрос всеми необходимыми деталями.

Comment: да я это имел ввиду, только обрезать строку с `C:\Users\Public` до `Public` можно легко, но это костыльно решение, желательно найти какой то аналог `Directory.GetDirectories(argument)` который будет выдавать лист только с именами папкок из оприделенной директории

Comment: @Selasi Немного неочевидно, но вместо `Path.GetDirectoryName` используй `Path.GetFileName`.

Comment: Directory.GetFiles("path/to/dir", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Comment: После `GetDirectories()` пишем `.Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x))`, далее `+= dI` меняем на `+= dI.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

тут всего один вариант получения последней папки, который работает для разных случаев:

```
var dir = @"c:\folder1\folder2";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir)); //c:\folder1 - FAIL
Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name); //folder2 - OK
Console.WriteLine(dir.Split('\\').LastOrDefault()); //folder2 - OK
Console.WriteLine();

dir = @"c:\folder1\folder2\";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir)); //c:\folder1\folder2 - FAIL
Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name); //folder2 - OK
Console.WriteLine(dir.Split('\\').LastOrDefault()); //null - FAIL
Console.WriteLine();

dir = @"c:/folder1/folder2";
Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir)); //c:\folder1 - FAIL
Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(dir).Name); //folder2 - OK
Console.WriteLine(dir.Split('\\').LastOrDefault()); //c:/folder1/folder2 - FAIL
Console.WriteLine();
```

П.С. напишем теперь полный код получения списка папок внутри заданного родителя (выведем их как команда dir):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dir(@"c:\");
}

static void Dir(string argument)
{
    string dirs = "";
    foreach (string dI in Directory.GetDirectories(argument))
    {
        dirs += new DirectoryInfo(dI).Name + "\n";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(dirs);
}
```

Comment: это все конечно увлекательно, но мне нужно получить список папок которые находяться в folder2, а фильтровать каждую из них такое себе

Comment: дополнил. надеюсь, это то, что нужно.